# Page Not Found error while searching Marklogic transforms

Tags: rest, marklogic

I'm trying to implement transforms in Marklogic using example from this [link](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#id_48952)

When I try to install transform using following curl command

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X PUT -d@"./add-attr.xqy" -H "Content-type: application/xquery" 'http://localhost:8000/LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr?trans:name=string\?&trans:value=string\?'
```

it's giving me errors like (using curl)

```
<div><h3>Message</h3><div style="width: 100%; height: 300px; overflow: auto;"><pre>&lt;error:error xsi:schemaLocation="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error error.xsd" xmlns:error="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;
&lt;error:code&gt;XDMP-BADREP&lt;/error:code&gt;
&lt;error:name&gt;err:FORX0004&lt;/error:name&gt;
&lt;error:xquery-version&gt;1.0-ml&lt;/error:xquery-version&gt;
&lt;error:message&gt;Invalid replacement string&lt;/error:message&gt;
&lt;error:format-string&gt;XDMP-BADREP: (err:FORX0004) fn:replace("/LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr", attribute{fn:QName("", "uri")}{"^/(common-api|dashboard|history|manage|nav|packaging|rest-apis)(..."}, &amp;lt;rest:uri-param name="url" xmlns:rest="http://marklogic.com/appservices/rest"&amp;gt;/LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr?trans:name=string\?&amp;amp;amp;trans...&amp;lt;/rest:uri-param&amp;gt;) -- Invalid replacement string: /LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr?trans:name=string\?&amp;amp;trans:value=string\?&lt;/error:format-string&gt;
&lt;error:retryable&gt;false&lt;/error:retryable&gt;
&lt;error:expr&gt;fn:replace("/LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr", attribute{fn:QName("", "uri")}{"^/(common-api|dashboard|history|manage|nav|packaging|rest-apis)(..."}, &amp;lt;rest:uri-param name="url" xmlns:rest="http://marklogic.com/appservices/rest"&amp;gt;/LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr?trans:name=string\?&amp;amp;amp;trans...&amp;lt;/rest:uri-param&amp;gt;)&lt;/error:expr&gt;
&lt;error:data&gt;
&lt;error:datum&gt;/LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr?trans:name=string\?&amp;amp;trans:value=string\?&lt;/error:datum&gt;
```

I even tried using **Postman-chrome app** and it's giving me **401 Unauthorized** error.

even when I'm checking for available transforms using

```
http://localhost:8000/v1/config/transforms
```

It's giving me **Page Not Found** exception[image]

I'm trying with *admin* user which have all the admin permissions

What am I missing here? How can I build transform for REST calls?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same error, but only if I run the above command against MarkLogic 7. MarkLogic 7 is not running a REST-api on port 8000, that is new in MarkLogic 8.

Next to this you should use url encoding instead of regex escaping for the question mark in trans:xxx request parameter values, e.g.:

```
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X PUT -d@"./add-attr.xqy" -H "Content-type: application/xquery" 'http://localhost:8000/LATEST/config/transforms/add-attr?trans:name=string%3F&trans:value=string%3F'
```

HTH!

Comment: Y.Prithvi, you could either upgrade to MarkLogic 8 or run this against a different port where you've [set up a REST API app server](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021).